# How to use the conditional operator on $_POST array in PHP?

Tags: php

```
$myitem = $_POST['item1'] ? myitem : NULL ;
```

is this possible? I got an error `Notice: Undefined index`

I use conditioning number of object items by ajax. for example sometime $_POST['item1'] is not passed.

Answer (score 9):

Use `isset()` for the condition and `$_POST['item1']` after the question mark.

```
$myitem = isset($_POST['item1']) ? $_POST['item1'] : NULL;
```

Comment: Hi! Did my answer help you? I would appreciate if you could accept the answer if it did. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use `array_key_exists()` in place of `isset()` as the latter one checks for the value also! For example, if the user enter's the number '0' in a field, `isset()` and `empty()` will return `false` while `array_key_exists()` will return `true`.

Your code becomes:

```
$myitem = array_key_exists($_POST['item1']) ? $_POST['item1'] : NULL ;
```

This is a mistake that most new PHP developers make and it hides in plain sight, giving them nightmares!